# Using oathtool instead of Microsoft Authenticator

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I have enabled 2FA on my outlook account (microsoft). It asked me to download the Microsoft Authenticator app and gave me a 9 digit number, e.g. '123456789'.

I wouldn't like to use the MS app, can I use oathtool instead?

I tried all of the following, it all gave the same error:
"*oathtool: hex decoding of secret key failed*"

```
oathtool -w 123456789
oathtool -b --totp '123456789'
oathtool --base32 --totp "123456789"
```

Comment: The secret code for the authenticator should have been longer than 9 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a TOTP key – it's a pairing code specifically for Microsoft Authenticator's online setup (most likely for its "push" 2FA feature).

During the process, you should've had a link to "set up a different Authenticator app":

[image]

That link will lead you to a page **containing a Qr code.** Either scan it (using `zbarimg` if you want) or click "I can't scan the code" and the page will reveal the TOTP secret key.

Note that the key will (at nearly all websites) be in Base32 format, not hexadecimal.

[image]

If the process you're seeing is different, visit https://account.live.com/proofs/manage/additional and select "Add a new way".

Comment: If this is a enterprise-style account with enforced 2FA settings, then the thing won't offer an alternative. I am in https://mysignins.microsoft.com/security-info and see this instead: https://t.co/kcwkRhbjrR . Now if I follow your URL, it says "That Microsoft account doesn't exist. Enter a different account or *get a new one*." Then if I click "*get a new one*", it responds with "You can't sign up here with a work or school email address."

Comment: PS.  I guess it's a no go for the folks at universities that use MS-based auth. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you have copied code from the online
manual and are using it in your command.

The article
[Annoyance with examples in online manual](https://www.mail-archive.com/oath-toolkit-help@nongnu.org/msg00531.html)
describes the problem:

> On the page at http://www.nongnu.org/oath-toolkit/oathtool.1.html
> http://www.nongnu.org/oath-toolkit/oathtool.1.html there are several
> examples. Copying/pasting these, at least from Firefox on a Mac, into
> a  terminal fails for many of them, giving errors like "oathtool: hex
> decoding of  secret key failed”.
>
> This is because on the web page the dashes in arguments such as
> “—totp” are  actually unicode minus signs, U+2212, instead of ASCII
> dash (0x2d) which is  what the program expects.

If this is the problem, I suggest to get your examples by copy/paste
from "man oathtool" in another terminal.